# Multi-level nested count in ActiveRecord (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I feel a little out of my depth here. I've got the following relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flights
end

class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flight_legs
    belongs_to :user
end

class FlightLeg < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :departure_airport, :class_name => "Airport"
    belongs_to :arrival_airport, :class_name => "Airport"
end

class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :country
      has_many :flight_legs_arriving_here, :class_name => "FlightLeg",
        :foreign_key => "arrival_airport_id"
      has_many :flight_legs_departing_here, :class_name => "FlightLeg",
        :foreign_key => "departure_airport_id"
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :airports
end
```

I want to get a list of users by the number of countries that they have visited, and a separate query which will return the number of countries a user has visited. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I am sort of lost with the details of the documentation on this one.